# How do I query tables from different databases?

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

How would I join tables from different databases?

example join table_1(db1) and table_2 (db2) and then return some FK values

- Does SQLS support cross database FK relationships?
- How would you ensure integrity?
- How would the syntax look when joining db2 with a FK reference?

```
SELECT
tb1.ID,
b.Name as Bid,
o.Name as Outcome

From table1 as tb1 
left join bid as b on b.ID = g.ID 
left join outcome as o on o.ID = g.ID
```

Comment: Just reference the table as `DatabaseName.SchemeName.TableName`

Answer (score 2):

The full name of the table on SQL Server has a format

```
[database].[schema].[table]
```

So if you have two tables in different databases on the one server you can join them this way.

```
select * 
  from first_db.dbo.table1 a
  inner join second_database.dbo.table2 b on a.id = b.id
```

Let me know if you need more explanations.